# Enabling dynamic debug makes my camera driver behave better

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver

I am prototyping the driver for an 8 bit parallel image sensor on an ARM device with a built-in ISP. I will spare the details, as I seek for general guide on how to approach this particular problem I am having.

Simply put, when I load the ISP driver (not my prototype camera driver) with `dyndbg=+pt` flag, the camera driver usually grabs images (about ~8 out of 10 attempts). If I remove the flag, and load the ISP driver without any options, my camera driver rarely finishes its job (about 1 out of ~100 attempts). The system gets stuck saying the device has timed out.

I suspect loading the driver with debug flag is somehow altering the timing, resulting more stable interaction between the ISP and the image sensor. I mostly spend my hours debugging electrical aspects of embedded boards, and rarely delve into a deep software stack such as ISP or Video4Linux. Hence my conjecture may be completely off.

Therefore some pointers will be much appreciated. The kernel is 3.18.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided a lot of details for us to work with here, but if enabling debug is making your device work, my suspicion would be that the debug output is introducing a delay which is required for your device to work properly. I'd read through your device datasheets carefully to see if there are any timing requirements you might not be respecting.